# PUT Request to Update data in Mongodb Not Working (Nodejs API)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, put

This is the first time I write a question, I've tried to resolve this issue by myself but I can't find the solution, so I ended up here.

In this project I'm currently working with MongoDB, NodeJS & Express. Also I've made an API in order to interact with the mongo database. I made a GET, POST
Here I represent the file structure

```
    |-- my-project
    |-- .gitignore
    |-- app.js
    |-- package-lock.json
    |-- package.json
    |-- README.md
    |-- assets
    |-- controllers
    |-- data
    |   |-- testimonials.json
    |-- model
    |   |-- database.js
    |   |-- testimonials.dao.js
    |-- public
    |-- routers
    |   |-- testimonialsApiRouter.js
```

In the app.js I import express and router

```js
    import express from "express";
    import pageRouter from "./routers/pageRouter.js";
    import testimonialsApiRouter from "./routers/testimonialsApiRouter.js"; 
    
    const app = express();
    
    app.set("views", "./views");
    app.set("view engine", "ejs");
    
    
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(express.json());
    
    app.use(express.static("public"));
    
    app.use("/api/testimonials", testimonialsApiRouter);
    
    app.listen(80, function () {
      console.log("el servidor esta encendido");
    });
```

In the `testimonialsApiRouter.js` I made a function so everytime the api made a put action, to call the dao and execute the `replaceById` function with the request params id as a parameter in the function.

```js
    import express from "express";
     
    import dao from '../model/testimonials.dao.js'
    const router = express.Router(); 
       
        router.route("/:id")
    .get(function (req, res) {
      dao.findById(req.params.id)
      .then(function (testimonial) {
          if(testimonial == null){
            res.json(`not found`);
          }
          else {
            res.status(200).json(testimonial);
      }
      }) 
        .catch(function (err) {
          res.status(404).json({
            err: 404,
            msg: `no se encuentra el testimonio id: ${req.params.id}`,
          });
        });
    })

      router.route("/replace/:id/")
      .put(function (req, res) {
        dao.replaceById(req.params.id)
        .then(function (testimonial) {
          res.status(200).json(`successful replacement `);
        }) 
          .catch(function (err) {
            res.status(404).json({
              err: 404,
              msg: `not found`,
            });
          });
         
      })
    export default router;
```

In the `database.js` I made an async function named connection to connect to the mongo database

```js
    import mongodb from 'mongodb'
    const client = new mongodb.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')
    
    export async function connection(callback){
        await client.connect()
    
        const result = await callback(client.db("DBName"))
    
        await client.close()
    
        return result
    }
```

In the `testimonials.dao.js` I import the `connection.js` to interact with the mongo database. Also in `testimonials.dao.js` i made the `replaceById()` function that returns the connection callback function and returns a promise, if the connection success, the collection from the database is returned and calls the `replaceOne` method that accepts as first parameter the `mongodb.ObjectId`  to be replaced and as second parameter the json object to replace. Here I think it's the problem, I'm not sure if `{name:body.name}` it's ok to tell the function that replace the original document with the object I pass in the body request.

```js
    import mongodb from 'mongodb'
    import {connection} from './database.js'
      
    export async function replaceById(id){
        return connection(async function(db){ 
            return await db.collection("Testimonials").replaceOne({_id: mongodb.ObjectId(id)},{name:req.body.name})
        }) 
    }  
        export async function findById(id){
        return conexion(async function(db){
            return await db.collection("Testimonials").findOne({_id: mongodb.ObjectId(id)})  
        })  
    }
    
    export default {
           replaceById,
           findById 
    }
```

When I execute the put method via the API to the URI `localhost/api/testimonials/replace/:id`
I receive a 404 Not Found error.
But the `ObjectId` currently exists in the database.

[image: the put method response via the API]

[image: the get method response via the API]

This is the json collection from mongo

```json
        [{
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "615f8182e9732fa6c42e2b84"
      },
      "name": "Lucia",
      "linkedin": "luciagonzalez",
      "description": "Awful",  
    },{
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "615f8182e9732fa6c42e2b85"
      },
      "web": true,
      "description": "Nice",
      "linkedin": "johndoe",
      "name": "John Doe"
    },{
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6168c438ab503b42b3ec33d6"
      },
      "name": "Maximiliano",
      "linkedin": "mcolombatti",
      "description": "Bad", 
    }]
```

Any assist or help would be really apreciated.

Comment: What was the error you catch over at .catch(function (err) before sending the 404 error message

Comment: Status: 404 Not Found 
{
  "err": 404,
  "msg": "not found"
}

Comment: I solved the problem.I manage to send information in the body request as an entity object and then I pass the entity as a parameter to the `replaceById` function.  `export async function replaceById(id, entity){return conexion(async function(db){ return await db.collection("Testimonials").replaceOne({_id: mongodb.ObjectId(id)}, entity )})}  `.Thanks for the assistance. Anyways I think It's always better to solve the problems by your own and in case you're stuck you can ask for assistance.